# Get the synced device list and synced device history from chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-history

I am trying to get the synced device list and history from those synced devices. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a direct way to do what you need. But this is worth a try.

1. Oauth2 google login through your chrome extension. This should help you with that - http://smus.com/oauth2-chrome-extensions/.
2. Get the email id of the. This should help you with that. [Can my extension get a user's e-mail address from Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394229/can-my-extension-get-a-users-e-mail-address-from-google-chrome). We need it to get the Customer_ID to use the google apis.
3. Get the customer ID using gmail ID. This should help help you with that.
   https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_user
4. And finally the google api to retrieve the synced mobile device details.
   https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-mobile-devices. This step cannot be done through your extension directly. You might have to create a webapp and host it somewhere(heroku hosting maybe. Its free for a single dyno). And then send requests from the host to the google apis through your extension.

Looks complicated but is supposed to work.

I have worked on these a bit. I think I can help if get stuck somewhere.